# Lists of lists in pandas.DataFrame constructor - an edge case?

Tags: pandas

Here's where I run into trouble:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame( index = [1,3,5,7,11] )
df['lists'] = [ ['a'],['b'],['c'],['a',b'],['a','b','c'] ]
df['listOflists'] = [ [['a']], [['b'],['a']], [['c']], [['d']], [['e']] ]
df['listOfLists1'] = [ [['a']], [['b']], [['a','c']], [['a','b','d']], [['e']] ]
print df
df['listOfLists_fails'] = [ [['a']], [['b']], [['a']], [['d']], [['e']] ]
```

The last example (only) throws an error in 0.11.0. One could get around this by assigning elementwise I suppose, but that seems ugly. Anyone know what is going on behind the scenes?

Comment: Works fine in pandas 0.14.0

Comment: I *strongly* recommend upgrading.  Apart from significant improvements, there have also been many bugfixes.  (`pandas` is one of the few projects I make sure to stay current with.)

Comment: note that using list-of-lists in a dataframe is not very efficient.